# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS wired internet extremely slow

Tags: 14.04, ethernet, realtek

My wired internet is running extremely slow after installing Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop. my normal internet speed (Windows) using speedtest.net is around 25 mbps, Ubuntu is pulling in 0.5 mbps tops.

I've found lots of issues with the 'Realtek RTL8111 Ethernet Interface' I've got, they all say to change the drivers to r8168 (which I've done) or change the IPv6 to ignore (also done) but my internet is still running extremely slow. I've tried everything I've been able to find online and rebooted multiple times along the way but all to no avail. I don't have much experience with Linux, but am eager to learn.

What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: I would probably try getting a live ISO from a different Linux distribution and testing it to see if it's either an Ubuntu-specific issue or a Linux-specific issue. For example, you could try out Sabayon and see if it has the same problem while in the live environment.

Comment: I have used the Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 motherboard which has a Realtek 8111E NIC. There were just way too many problems with the ethernet and the solution I ended up going with was a PCI LAN port.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slow wired internet connection on Realtek RTL8168-8111 (Rev 6)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71252/slow-wired-internet-connection-on-realtek-rtl8168-8111-rev-6)

Comment: another page you don't even have to scroll down to know there's no accepted (==working) answer :) [whoever messed up 14.04 network testing -- freak you hard]

Answer (score 11):

1. Disconnect from Internet
2. Open your Terminal and execute the line:

   ```
   sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 <<<"1"
   ```
3. Connect to the Internet again, and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: How do we reverse this?

Comment: @Arin the above command was simply writing a 1 to the file, you can reset it to a 0 by using this command: `sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 <<<"0"`

Answer (score 5):

**Fix the bug in Debian Avahi-daemon**

The slow WiFi in Ubuntu problem could also be related to a bug in Avahi-daemon of Debian. Ubuntu and many other Linux distribution are based on Ubuntu so this bug propagates to several Linux distributions. To fix this bug, you have to edit the nsswitch configuration file. Open a terminal and use the following command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

This will open the configuration file in gedit so that you could edit it easily in GUI. In here, look for the following line:

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

If you find this file, replace it with the following line:

```
hosts: files dns
```

Save it, close it, restart your computer. It should fix the slow wireless connection problem for you. If it doesn’t check the other solution.

Works for me. Hope same does for you :) If it dosen't , try other solutions , from here http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/