# Wifi extremely slow in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

I understand that this question has been done a lot, but I'm asking because i still haven't found a solution.

I have and Asus x200ma-ub01t that dual boots Windows 10(technical preview) and Ubuntu 14.04.2.
Everything works fine and performance is superb, but i have one problem in Ubuntu that is bugging me. The wifi in Ubuntu is extremely slow compared to windows. I have looked through count less posts dealing with the same problem but have not found a solution. However, i am open to any and all suggestions. If you need the output of any command (I bet you will) just ask :) thanks in advance!

Comment: Go to `http://speedtest.net` and run a speed test. Run on both Windows and Ubuntu **using the same server**. Then put the results in the question/comment.

Comment: I ran speedtest in windows 10 and got 32 mbps down and 5 mbps up. In ubuntu, got less than 1 mbps down and about 1 mbps up. :(

Comment: Which WiFi-chip is build in into this box?

Comment: the wifi chip is a realtek rtl8188ee and the driver is r8169

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was a last resort but i did it. I decided to use and external usb adapter to speed up the wifi, and it worked! My wifi is at a good speed, although it was unfortunate it came to this. Oh well, i personally believe that graphics and wifi drivers (as well as drivers in general) is that ubuntu really struggles with, and i hope it gets the compatibility and support that windows does.

Answer (score 0):

I also use X200MA, and [I tried this "IPv6 off" method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475493/ubuntu-14-04-lts-wired-internet-extremely-slow).

A little more speed up of X200MA Wifi.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and it did help a little bit. Im pretty surprised that the chip in this laptop doesnt work well with linux, but it should be solved eventually.

Answer (score 0):

New solution !

Use new Linux kernel 4.1 !  Getting much effective for my X200MA !

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1-rc1-vivid/

It seems that New kernel updates for BayTrails' suspend process, so Wifi driver and other functions are well activating after resume from suspend, I thought.