# 14.04 Lubuntu install randomly loses wired Internet connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, lubuntu, wired

I recently moved and ever since setting up my desktop, I've had seemingly random losses of my wired connection, although high bandwidth stuff (Netflix, maximizing an HD YouTube video) seems to trigger it fairly reliably.

I'm fairly certain it's something to do with Lubuntu.  After the last outage, I hooked up a laptop to the same port on the router with the same cable and it connected just fine.  My wireless phone and tablet also maintain their Internet connection.

Rebooting temporarily fixes the issue.  Sometimes I need to reboot twice.

What do you need from me to diagnose? :)

Comment: Have you tried `sudo service network-manager restart` instead of rebooting ? Try that. There is list of connections in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory. Try deleting every single one of them and reconnect to your network ( and in case you need to keep settings for those networks, just back those files up with `sudo mv /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections ~/connections-backup` , making sure you have connections-backups first)

Comment: @Serg I have tried `sudo service network-manager restart` and it worked once.  I've also tried deleting all my network connections, though not through that method.

Comment: OK, so simply restarting network-manager and deleting connections doesn't help, right ? Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/475493/295286) question . Try couple of answers posted there. Let me know if any of those help. I am not well versed with internet issues, but I'll keep tabs on your questions, and let's see together if we can figure this out

Comment: @Serg I've attempted all those answers, no luck.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem. `sudo service network-manager restart` doesn't fix it for me. The only thing that fixes it is a full reboot with `sudo shutdown -r now`.

This is happening on a little Lenovo Q190 compact HTPC, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's a driver issue with the onboard ethernet port. But if you're also experiencing it on a plain desktop PC, then maybe it's a more common issue.

@jesuskiosk - Did you ever find a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you said you hooked up a laptop to the same cable/port etc but you were not using the same ethernet hw that you have in what I assume is a desktop?

Rebooting your PC also reinitializes the hw in the PC including the ethernet port.

Before you assume its Lubuntu... why don't you boot up a "liveCD" of ubuntu or lubuntu etc on the PC and see if it then works.   If you still have network problems then you might have to assume its the ethernet card/hw in the PC causing your problems.

If it is a desktop PC, if the ethernet is an add-in card .. maybe it got knocked loose in the move and isn't seated correctly?

Comment: The Ethernet port is integrated on the motherboard.  I'm a little skeptical that a reboot would consistently fix the issue if it was some hardware defect, but it is getting old and has been through a lot of traveling (Gigabyte GA-EP35-DS3L).  I'll try a live CD sometime, though.